# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<BOL.tblchqNo>

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm getting above error in my following method:

```
public IEnumerable<tblchqNo> GetChqDetailsByCustName(string custname)
 {
  return _db.tblchqNoes.Where(x => x.custName == custname).Select(k => new 
  {k.chqNo,k.custName,k.status}).ToList();
 }
```

Comment: You're returning a list of anonymous objects

Comment: Change `Select(k => new {k.chqNo,k.custName,k.status})` to `Select(k => k)` or just use Where(x => x.custName == custname).ToList().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You projection `Select(...)` returns for each item of `_db.tblchqNoes` that passes you `Where` an anonymous type with three properties and not a `tblchqNo` object. So the return type of your method is not compatible to that your return. There are two options:

- Create a type with the three properties you want to return and change both the return type of your method and the type you use during the projection. If we suppose that the class you would define has the name `ShortChqNo` then you should made the following changes:

> **Change** 1
>
> public IEnumerable GetChqDetailsByCustName(string
>   custname)
>
> **Change 2**
>
> Select(k => new ShortChqNo {k.chqNo,k.custName,k.status}).ToList();

- Change the the type you project from the anonymous type you use to the `tblchqNo`.

> Select(k => new tblchqNo {k.chqNo,k.custName,k.status}).ToList();